# Can TypeScript be configured to error on Boolean compares force coercion?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-types

That is, I want to have it flagged as an error if my code does something like this:

```
const s = “true”
if (s === true)
```

Possible?

EDIT:

This is the line of code that stung me:

```
const showPlanToAttendOption =
     e.target.attributes["datashowplantoattendoption"].value;
```

Then compare true to the above.

I converted it to the below to work. I would have preferred an error

```
const showPlanToAttendOption = 
    e.target.attributes["data-showplantoattendoption"].value == "true";
```

Comment: hmmm... `const s: string = "true"; if (s === true) { ... }` will return an error: **This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'boolean' have no overlap**

Comment: I get that. I want it to show me an error so I don’t do this by accident

Comment: ...it's already flagged as an error, like zvona said.

Comment: I added some more context in the question as an edit

Comment: Actually, now that I look at it, that’s not the issue.  I compare to the string is what is causing my issue

Answer (score 0):

If the condition is always false because of no type overlap, TypeScript will tell you about it.

```
declare const something: string;

if (something === true) {} // Error: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'boolean' have no overlap.
```

However, when using implicit coercion, things can get tricky. To get an error in a scenario such as this:

```
declare const something: string;

if (something) {} // [strict-boolean-expressions] This type is not allowed in the 'if' condition because it could be undefined. Only booleans are allowed.
```

you will need TSLint and its [strict-boolean-expressions](https://palantir.github.io//tslint/rules/strict-boolean-expressions/) rule.